# Using method of React Native SDK returns undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, connectycube

I am using the ConnectyCube React Native SDK but not getting very far with it. When using its methods I am getting and error saying they are undefined like so: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSession' of undefined`. When I console.log `ConnectyCube.createSession` it logs:

`ƒ createSession(params, callback) {
      this.auth.createSession(params, callback);
    }`.

I have linked the package using `react-native link connectycube-reactnative` as I've read to do on other posts, but am still having the same problem. Anyone know what's wrong or how I could fix? Thanks in advance.

```
import ConnectyCube from 'connectycube-reactnative'
import config from './ConnectycubeConfig'

export default function App() { 

  console.log(ConnectyCube.createSession)

  var userCredentials = {login: 'xxxxxxxxx', password: 'xxxxxxxx'};

  ConnectyCube.createSession(userCredentials, (error, session) => {

  }); // 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSession' of undefined'
```

Comment: According to the documentation your import is wrong, it should be `import { ConnectyCube } from 'connectycube-reactnative'`. See the NPM package page.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but when I use that I get  `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. It also says you should use `const CB = new ConnectyCube()`, but then what? In the example apps they provide that work, they don't use either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set it up and `proceed` with the `session`.

```js
import ConnectyCube from 'connectycube-reactnative'
...
const cbConfig = [
    {
        appId: 218,
        authKey: 'p-cqm2aatn8ZPM3',
        authSecret: '3hmGuXN8AHZOgg6',
    },
    {
        debug: { mode: 1 },
    },
]
...
  componentWillMount() {
    ConnectyCube.init(...cbConfig)
    ConnectyCube.createSession((failSession, session) => {
      if (!failSession, session) {
       alert("you can get login")
      }
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iam no expert react. What is see is there is common problem. According to your error, it says that 'connectyCude' is undefined. Try below code.

```
import {ConnectyCube} from 'connectycube-reactnative'
import config from './ConnectycubeConfig'

export default function App() { 
  var cCube = new ConnectyCube();
  console.log(cCube.createSession)

  var userCredentials = {login: 'xxxxxxxxx', password: 'xxxxxxxx'};

  cCube.createSession(userCredentials, (error, session) => {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSession' of undefined`

Comment: The console log still returns `ƒ createSession(params, callback) {
      this.auth.createSession(params, callback);
    }`

Comment: Interestingly I am getting a warning in VS Code on the import. It says `Could not find a declaration file for module 'connectycube-reactnative'.` There are three dots just after `from`.

Comment: Try initialize it before calling ''createSession''